# How to reference to element from state in foreach (Vuex)?

Tags: vue.js, foreach, vuex, store

I am using vuex in my vue application. In store is a declared object:

```
    state: {
        list: {
            a: false,
            b: false,
            c: false
        }
    }
```

In mutations is mutation that receives arrays in parameters, for example: `el: ['a', 'b']`.
Those elements in the `el` array must be set to true in `list` object in state. I'm using a foreach loop for this:

```
    mutations: {
        SET_LIST(state, el) {
            el.forEach(element => {
                if (state.list.element) {
                    state.list.element = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error: `error  'element' is defined but never used`.
Because `element` is not used and I don't know how to refer to it correctly.

I searched on the internet and found this solution: `state.list[element]`. I don't get an error then, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) `[]` to get the property dynamically :

```
   mutations: {
        SET_LIST(state, el) {
            el.forEach(element => {
                if (Object.keys(state.list).includes(element)) {
                    state.list[element] = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, in this solution when I call `commit ('SET_LIST', ["a"])` ,  then `if (state.list[element])` never gets called

Comment: replace `if (state.list.element)` by `if (state.list.hasOwnProperty(element))`

Comment: I am getting error: `Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object`

Comment: Try out `if(Object.keys(state.list).includes(element))`